# How to convert a function to be used as int in Python? or is that even possible?

Tags: python, function, int

Problem:
I cannot and do not know how will i use/convert the function position to be an input/integer to the function find_second.

---

Code

```
  # Define a procedure, find_second, that takes
  # two strings as its inputs: a search string
  # and a target string. It should return a
  # number that is the position of the second
  # occurrence of the target string in the
  # search string.

def position (search_string, target):
    position_target = search_string.find(target)
    return int(position_target)

def find_second (search_string, second_target):
    return search_string.find(second_target, position+1)

danton = "De l'audace, encore de l'audace, toujours de l'audace"

print find_second(danton, 'audace')`
```

---

Error Msg:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "vm_main.py", line 33, in <module>
import main
File "/tmp/vmuser_laavqhjazh/main.py", line 19, in <module>
print find_second(danton, 'audace')
File "/tmp/vmuser_laavqhjazh/main.py", line 13, in find_second
return search_string.find(second_target, position+1)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'function' and 'int'
```

Comment: Presumably, you want `position(search_string, second_target) + 1`, possibly with different arguments?

Comment: You need to actually *call* the function.

Comment: @chepner Thank you, it worked!! :P

Answer (score 0):

position is a function. An alternative is:

```
def find_second(search_string, target):
    temp = search_string.find(target)
    return search_string.find(target, temp)

danton = "De l'audace, encore de l'audace, toujours de l'audace"

print find_second(danton, 'audace')`
```